# Format Date via Parameter

Tags: asp.net

I have a DateTime variable (default formatting), and I would like to format it to a format to I receive from a string parameter.

I normally do something similar to: {myDate:yyyy-MM-dd}, and it works properly.

Now I have a lot of possible date formats and need to format according to the chosen one.

I have tried the following but returned garbage (ae0aor0aa):

```
string testFormat = "yyyy. MM. dd.";
{myDate:testFormat }
```

I have also tried to convert the date to string and back to date with ParseExact, but gave me an invalid date exception. NB: the date in myDate is valid, as I have checked it with the debugger.

Can you kindly advise?

Comment: Parsing is a much stricter than converting to string, ideally you should store your date object and only covert to a string format for displaying.
Have you tried myDate.ToString(testFormat) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to apc, it was easily solved by `myDate.ToString(testFormat)`